# Juno won't open julia

Tags: julia, juno-ide

I am trying to run juno in atom because I hope it will be easier to debug code than it has been for me in vs studio but upon starting julia from juno I received the following error message in an orange box in the top right:

Julia could not be started.

Couldn’t resolve version.

We tried to launch Julia from: julia This path can be changed in the settings.

Where in settings can this be changed? It is not clear to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to open the Settings tab (`Ctrl+,`), then go to Packages > julia-client.

The path is the first setting:

[image]

Comment: is this the same as:  https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-can-i-reset-my-julia-path-in-atom/47818 , or it is somehow a different way to do it?

Comment: Slightly different - in your link the poster uses `PATH`, i.e. system variables, to set the julie executable location. This is what Atom uses if you don't specify a path, as in my screenshot above. Alternatively, you can add a full path in the settings, in which case the `PATH` variable will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Nils's suggestion, here's a lazy approach that has worked for me on MacOS BigSur and probably works on other systems.

1. Go to Juno Settings
2. Go to the Uber-Juno Settings (scroll down)
3. De-select: Disable (Don't run installation on Atom startup)
4. Exit Atom and re-start.

What this does is force Atom to run the installation script on startup. Atom then looks for Julia on your system and, in my case, found it easily. Problem solved.